# AJAX POST request with form Token always responds with "Invalid Token"

Tags: joomla-3.x, session, security-token

I'm sending data from a form with AJAX.
The data is a username and password of the user, and therefore I want to make it as secure as possible.

I'm trying to use a `token` as an extra security layer, but it always return as "**invalid**".

I've gone through https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms and can't see that anything should be wrong.

My login form:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="userForm">
    <label for="username">Brugernavn</label>    
    <input type="text" value="" name="username">    
    <label for="password">Password</label>  
    <input type="password" value="" name="password">
    <?php echo JHtml::_( 'form.token' ); ?>
    <button id="login-user">Login</button>
</form>
```

The AJAX request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?option=com_content&format=ajax&view=article&task=loginUser&tmpl=component',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        form: jQuery(form).serializeArray()
    },
    async: true,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        var result = response;

        if ( result.loggedIn == 1 ) {                   
            //User logged in
            jQuery('#loginModal').modal('hide');
        }
        else {                  
            //User not logged in                
        }               
    }
});
```

The function that gets called in my `view.ajax.php`

```
public function _logInUser( $form ){

    $options = array();
    $credentials = array();

    var_dump($form);
    JSession::checkToken() or die( 'Invalid Token' );
    $credentials['username'] = $form[0]['value'];
    $credentials['password'] = $form[1]['value'];

    $result = JFactory::getApplication()->login($credentials, $options);        
    $result = ($result) ? 1 : 0;

    //1     - logged in
    //0     - not logged in     
    echo json_encode( array('loggedIn' => $result) );                   
    jexit();

}
```

And the output in my console from `var_dump($form);`

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "username"
    ["value"]=>
    string(20) "myusername@something.dk"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "password"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "mypassword123"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(32) "dc56f674238905e70ab3d98f9bb6e2f0"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
Invalid Token
```

The only thing else I can think of, is that `&format=ajax` or `dataType: 'html'` should be something like `json` or maybe `raw` ...but when I tried that, then the call dosen't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default JSession::checkToken() checks the post request for a value named the token.  It can also be set to look for get values in a query string like JSession::checkToken('get').  It doesn't know that a variable you've serialized manually in a structure you built yourself and called 'form' is where to find the token.

To test it manually you could do something like the following:

```
if ($form[2]['name'] != JSession::getFormToken()){die();}
```

I haven't tested that but I don't see why it shouldn't work.  Once a csrf token is made for the session it generally stays the same.

Comment: Thanks!! Works :) ...I don't understand why this is not an example on the Joomla documentation under "Checking the Token"... It only says "use `JSession::checkToken() or die( 'Invalid Token' );`"